# Making a simple registrarion/login using node.js and mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im trying to make a simple registration/login for a school project but i dont really know how to check if the user already exists in the database and send the response back to the client and inform the user that the username he is trying to use is already taken, this is the code i was using

```js
function confirm(username, email, password, callback) {
    var post = { username: username, email: email, password: password };
    var params = [post.username, post.email];
    var queryTest = global.connect.con.query('SELECT username, email FROM Utilizador WHERE username = ? AND email = ?', params, function(err, rows, fields) {
        console.log(rows);
        if (!err) {
            if (rows != "") {
                console.log("user already exists");
            }
            else {
                var query = global.connect.con.query('INSERT INTO Utilizador SET ?', post, function(err, rows, fields) {
                    console.log(query.sql);
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log("Number of records inserted: " + rows.affectedRows);
                    }
                    else
                        console.log('Error while performing Query.', err);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

instead of "console.log("user already exists");" i want to send an alert saying the same thing, but if i use an alert it does not work. obviously that isn't the only code i'm using but i'm not really sure what do i need to post here in order for anyone to understand my problem so if necessary i can post the rest.

Comment: If by `i want to send an alert saying the same thing` you mean: `window.alert` the one you use on the browser, you can't use it on Node.js, it's a Web API, which works on the browser only.

Comment: just pass the `alert msg` to your `callback` then you can show it in front-end example                                                                                                     `callback({message: "You are not logged in", status: false});`

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming the code here is in NodeJS)

The code here is in NodeJS and alert is defined on window object, in the browser. This is why you get error when you try to run this with alert.

The way to do is that you can send a custom response from your node API and and then use that on client to show the alert.

example (assuming you are using express)-

`resp.send('DUPLICATE')` from your API to signal to client that this user already exists.

Then, in browser -

`if (resp.body.status === 'DUPLICATE') { alert("This name already exists")}`

Comment: That wouldn't work. `res.status` is an alias to https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statuscode which expects a `Number` type.